# IndexError: list assignment index out of range for non-empty list

Tags: python

I am trying the following code

```
def getCount(mySet):
    l = len(mySet)
    hsh={}
    lSet=[]
    rSet=[]
    for i in range(0,l-1):
        for j in range(i+1,l):
            if ((mySet[i]+mySet[j])%k==0):
                lSet = mySet
                rSet = mySet
                print "i, j ", i,j
                del lSet[i]
                del rSet[j]
                if len(lSet)==0 or len(rSet==0):
                    return 0
                left = getCount(lSet)
                right = getCount(rSet)
                if left==right:
                    return left

    return len(lSet)

n,k = [int(i) for i in raw_input().split(" ")]

mySet=[]

for x in raw_input().split(" "):
    mySet.append(int(x))

print getCount(mySet)
```

where an example input is

```
5 5
2 4 1 6 8
```

however, I am getting the error

```
del rSet[j]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I don't understand why this is. How is `j` out of range?. In the line above, I printed out

```
i, j  0 4
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why this is. How is j out of range?. In the line above, I printed out

That is because, the moment you delete `lSet[i]`, the same element gets deleted from `rSet` too! And this happens because both the variables `lSet` and `rSet` refer to the same variable. To create a copy, you would do:

```
lSet = mySet[:]
rSet = mySet[:]
```

Comment: to circumvent the mutability issue, you can also use `deepcopy` from the [copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) library to make separate sets

Comment: True, but not required in this case because the list contains only integers.

Comment: Definitely not required; just another option